# MYSQL Lookup Email in 3 Tables from PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

I have three tables `safe_workers, safe_companies and safe_customers` which are used to store different account types. Upon login, I need a query to lookup the LoginEmail and LoginPassword columns in all three tables and return the match based on the login form passed by the login page.

I am a beginner to MySQL and tried the following but obviously it returns an error .

```
select safe_companies.LoginEmail,ID 
from safe_companies,safe_customers 
WHERE LoginEmail='.$_POST[InEmail].' AND LoginPass= '.$_POST[InPass].'
```

I dont want to compare tables just want to match

Comment: We need to know what the join conditions on your table are. This is a pretty easy query after that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question well:

What you're looking for are http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

If both tables have a colum named LoginEmail.

```
SELECT
    sco.LoginEmail
FROM
   safe_companies AS sco
INNER JOIN
    safe_customers AS scu ON (sco.LoginEmail = scu.LoginEmail)
WHERE
    sco.LoginEmail = '" . $_POST['InEmail'] . "' AND
    scu.LoginPass = '" . $_POST['InPass'] . "'
```

If not, please provide more info, like table structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UNION` statement to accomplish that. Try this:

```php
$dbh = new PDO('...');

$where = 'WHERE LoginEmail = :email AND LoginPass = :pass';
$query = [];
foreach (['safe_workers', 'safe_companies', 'safe_customers'] as $table) {
    $query[] = "(SELECT LoginEmail, ID FROM {$table} {$where})";
}

/*
 * This will become something like this:
 * (SELECT LoginEmail, ID FROM safe_workers WHERE LoginEmail = :email AND LoginPass = :pass)
 * UNION
 * (SELECT LoginEmail, ID FROM safe_companies WHERE LoginEmail = :email AND LoginPass = :pass)
 * UNION
 * (SELECT LoginEmail, ID FROM safe_customers WHERE LoginEmail = :email AND LoginPass = :pass)
 */
$stmt = $dbh->prepare(implode(' UNION ', $query));

$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['inEmail']);
$stmt->bindParam(':pass', $_POST['inPass']);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    var_dump($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}
```

*Note: I'm using PDO to prepare a statement and escape POST data. Take a look at its [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php).*

Comment: Thank you vcampitelli!! That solution worked!!! I don't understand JOIN yet but that's the next thing on my list to study about.

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption based on your question details that the LoginEmail and LoginPass value for a particular user will only exist in one of the three tables.  If that is the case you can use a UNION like below.

```
SELECT a.LoginEmail, a.ID
FROM (
    SELECT LoginEmail, ID FROM safe_workers
    UNION
    SELECT LoginEmail, ID FROM safe_companies
    UNION
    SELECT LoginEmail, ID FROM safe_customers
) AS a
WHERE a.LoginEmail = 'InEmail' AND a.LoginPass= 'InPass';
```

However, this could cause all sorts of bad.